# how can i validate if the user typed the form correctly in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

for context:
`$caregiverName = $_POST["caregiverName"];`
`$queryValidationCaregiverName = $conn->query("SELECT names FROM CaregiverRegistrationData");`

i tried all this approaches:

```
if ($queryValidationCaregiverName == $caregiverName){
        array_push($errors,"the name of the caregiver is mistyped. ");
    }
```

```
if ($queryValidationCaregiverName != $caregiverName){
        array_push($errors,"the name of the caregiver is mistyped. ");
    }
```

```
if ($queryValidationCaregiverName == $caregiverName){
        /* echo= "test"; */
    }else{
        array_push($errors,"the name of the caregiver is mistyped. ");
    }
```

```
if ($queryValidationCaregiverName != $caregiverName){
        /* echo= "test"; */
    }else{
        array_push($errors,"the name of the caregiver is mistyped. ");
    }
```

but none of them worked in the way that i wanted, what i wanted to do is, if the user dont type the name of the caregiver correctly, array_push occurs.

new code attempt:

```
$sql = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(names) FROM caregiverRegistrationData WHERE names = '$caregiverName'");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $caregiverName);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();

if(mysqli_num_rows($user)!=1){
    array_push($errors,"the name of the caregiver is mistyped. ");
}
```

2nd code attempt:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(names) as c FROM caregiverRegistrationData WHERE names = ?"
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $caregiverName);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user['c'] = $result->fetch_assoc();

if($user['c'] != $caregiverName){
    array_push($errors,"the name of the caregiver is mistyped. ");
}
```

Comment: Research how to use a `WHERE` clause. For your current issue `$queryValidationCaregiverName` is a result object, it cant be compared to a string. You need to fetch it.

Comment: @user3783243 so I added the where and fetched it, and now it's looking like that: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Ld0tOBvwPqU_Z8F2HcP_9F4AluEKOVf/view?usp=sharing just to give a little more context: I want to validate if the user typed correctly the name of the caregiver, so if right the result would be inserted in another table(this part is already working), but I assume that the problem right now is that $user is an array, not a string to be compared with $caregiverName, any suggestion of how to transform it or another approach that i can take?

Comment: Please post code in the question, not a link. You should use parameterized queries and prepared statements. You also should list what columns you want to select instead of selecting all columns. If you only need to know that there was a match select `count(*) as c` then check that the `c` index is >= 1.

Comment: i didnt use parameterized query there because if i put ```?``` instead of ```'$caregiverName'``` the code dont work, tried using prepared statements and the count() function, but it went wrong too: **the new code attempt is in the final part of the question itself, i tried putting it here but it unformatted**

Comment: `query` or `prepare` is to be used, never both (and I'd argue never `query`). So `$sql = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(names) as c FROM caregiverRegistrationData WHERE names = ?");` then use `$user['c']` to check the value. You don't use `mysqli_num_rows` with `count` as that will always give back 1 row. Need to check the actual number returned.

Comment: No, leave `$user = $result->fetch_assoc();` as you had it then `if($user['c'] >= 1) {` you have a match. The value is the count of names that matched the input.

Comment: so something like this? (above in ```2nd code attempy```), but the thing is, if i understood correctly, doing this process im atributing the result of my consult of the ```caregiverRegistrationData``` database to the variable ```$caregiverName```, but if its so, thats not what i planned to do, what i want is to compare the result of the consult = ```$sql``` (their correctly name that is in the database) with the name that the user typed = ```$caregiverName```(```$caregiverName = $_POST["caregiverName"];```) and if its wrong ```array_push``` with the error massage.

Comment: You are trying to check that `$_POST["caregiverName"]` is in the DB, right? ...and that value is stored in `$caregiverName`

Comment: no, im trying to compare what the used typed ```$_POST["caregiverName"]``` with the row ```names``` of the table ```caregiverRegistrationData```, if its correct then the the name typed ```$caregiverName = $_POST["caregiverName"];``` is inserted into another table ```apointments```(but the ```INSERT``` part is already done), if the name typed by the user in the text field of the form```<input type="text" name="caregiverName" id="caregiverNamecss">``` dont match the name that is in the ```caregiverRegistrationData``` table the array push is activated alerting that the user mistyped

Comment: Yes, so that is what this would do... well if implemented as written above `if($user['c'] >= 1) `

Comment: okay, gonna try and see if its works, also wanted to thank you for patience in trying to help me

Comment: Rough untested example https://3v4l.org/XbWrn, use `var_dump` to see what values are if you aren't sure what you are working with.

Comment: changed to ```!=``` instead of ```>=``` and its seems that is working just in the way that i wanted, gonna search, read and think a little more, because i dont understood very well how this piece of code worked, as what i thought was that the result of the sql command would be stored in the variable used in ```bind_param``` and this concept used in ```$user['c']``` is something that i hadnt seen yet, but again thank you so much for your patience and help

Comment: `var_dump($user['c'])` gives what? `>=` should be correct.  `bind_param` is what is being sent to the SQL. There is a `bind_result` which I never use. The `fetch` pulls the data and stores each column as an index to the variable the fetch is on. So `c` is the index where the count is.

Comment: ```var_dump($user['c'])```  gives "int 0"

Comment: So in that case the searched term did not match any values in the database. That is what you expect?

Comment: actually yes, because if the term would match any value in the database, the ```else``` part of my code would activate and the value would be inserted in the ```apointments``` table that i mentioned before